# Найти сумму элементов массива

Tags: php, массивы, float

Необходимо нати сумму всех элементов массива, каждый элемент которого равняется числу со значением после точки(float). Через array_sum() не вышло. Что подскажете?

```
<?php
    include('Users/eliasa/Desktop/prices/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
    $prices = array();
    getPRICES('http://www.ebay.com/sch/m.html?_ssn=couturerider&_pppn=r1&scp=ce1');

    function getPRICES($page) {
        global $prices;
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load_file($page);
        $items = $html->find('li[class=lvprice prc]'); 

        foreach($items as $names) {
            $prices[] = array($names->children(0)->plaintext);
        }

        foreach($prices as $item) {   
            $item[0] = ltrim($item[0], '$');
            echo str_replace('$', '', "$item[0] <br />");
        }
    }
?>
```

var_dump массива:

```
array(35) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) " $24.99" } 
    [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) " $350.00" } 
    [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) " $29.99" } 
    [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) " $19.99" } 
    [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) " $49.99" } 
    [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) " $49.99" } 
    [6]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) " $27.99" } 
    [7]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) " $24.99" } 
    [8]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) " $54.99" } 
    [9]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) " $14.99" } 
    [10]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) " $39.99" } 
    [11]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) " $9.99" }
}
```

Comment: приведите код, где у вас не получается вычислить сумму через `array_sum()`?

Comment: у вас может быть там строки с точкой в массиве а не float?

Comment: @teran что же тогда делать, если это просто строки?

Comment: пройтись по массиву и сложить элементы приводя их к float с помощью `floatval()` ?

Comment: вы price массив хотите сложить?

Comment: @Naumov да, его

Comment: Он двумерный же `$prices[] = array($names->children(0)->plaintext);` замени на `$prices[] = $names->children(0)->plaintext;` и потом уже `array_sum($prices)`

Comment: @Naumov вы поймите, что я пишу парсер цен с eBay и код их таким образом не выводит... ещё и компилятор говорит, что  мой массив должен быть массивом... как так?

Comment: dump массива в студию

Comment: @Naumov пробовал

Comment: что бробовал покажи массив какой перед суммированием?

Comment: @Naumov добавил. что скажете?

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = [[" $24.99"], [" $350.00"]];

$sum = 0.0;

array_walk_recursive($input, function($item) use (&$sum) {
    $sum += trim($item, "$ ");
});

var_dump($sum);
```

[результат выполнения](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8fe20bf74c8cba496b6b2bcf7b82c893ea740f9)

Answer (score 0):

В общем массив нужен не много мерный строки:

```
 foreach($items as $names) {
        $prices[] = array($names->children(0)->plaintext);
 }
```

меняем на

```
 foreach($items as $names) {
       // делаем одномерно и убираем лишнее
       $priceNumber = trim(
             str_replace('$','',strval($names->children(0)->plaintext))
       );
       $price[] = $priceString;
       // заменяем последний foreach
       echo $priceString . '<br />';
 }
```

далее можем суммировать

```
 array_sum($price);
```

Comment: что-то не работает...

Comment: @Ilia покажи полностью какой у тебя код получился?

Comment: include 'simple_html_dom.php'
    $prices = array();
    getPRICES('http://www.ebay.com/sch/m.html?_ssn=couturerider&_pppn=r1&scp=ce1');
    function getPRICES($page) {
        global $prices;
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load_file($page);
        $items = $html->find('li[class=lvprice prc]'); 
        foreach($items as $names) {
       $priceNumber = trim(
             str_replace('$','',$names->children(0)->plaintext));
       $price[] = $priceString;
       echo $priceString . '<br />';
 } echo array_sum($price);
 }

Comment: @Ilia в вопрос плиз вынеси не понятно ничего (( ошибки есть какие нибудь?

Comment: нет, просто выводит пустой столбец и внизу нолик

Comment: @Ilia понял поправил ответ в строку попробуй перевести

Comment: неа6 не фурычит...